# Vectorization instead of nested for loops in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am having trouble vectorizing this for loop in matlab which is really slow.
tvec and data are N×6 and N×4 arrays respectively, and they are the inputs to the function.

```
% preallocate
sVec = size(tvec) 
tvec_ab = zeros(sVec(1),6);
data_ab = zeros(sVec(1),4);
inc = 0;
for i = 1:12
    for j = 1:31
       inc = inc +1;
       [I,~] = find(tvec(:,3)==i & tvec(:,2)== j,1,'first');
       if(I > 0)
           tvec_ab(inc,:) = tvec(I,:);
           data_ab(inc,:) = sum(data( (tvec(:,3) == j) & (tvec(:,2)==i) ,:));
       end
    end
end

% set output values
tvec_a = tvec_ab(1:inc,:);
data_a = data_ab(1:inc,:);
```

Every row in `tvec` represents the timestamp where the data was taken in the same row in the data matrix. Below you can see how a row would look like:

`tvec`:
`[year, month, day, hour, minute, second]`

`data`:
`[dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD]`

In the main program we can choose to "aggregate" after month, day or hour.
The code above is an example of how the aggregation for the option `'DAY'` could happen.

the first time stamp of the day is the time stamp we want our output `tvec_a` to have in the row for that day.

The data output for that day (row in this case) would then be the sum of all the data for that day. Example:

`data`:

```
[data1ADay1, data1BDay1, data1CDay1, data1DDay1;
 data2ADay1, data2BDay1, data2CDay1, data2DDay1]
```

aggregated data:

```
[data1ADay1 + data2ADay1, data1BDay1 + data2BDay1, data1CDay1+ data2CDay1, 
data1DDay1+data2DDay1]
```

Comment: It seems that  N ==  12*31

Comment: Yes, in the resulting  matrix for this example N will be the result you described. However we do not know how large N from the input vector is and we do not know which aggregation option the user chooses ( in this case it is the aggregation of days, hence 12*31), But if the user for example chooses hours it will be N == 12*31*24

Comment: Sound like [`accumarray`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) is the way to go here

Comment: why in some place you write `tvec(:,3) == j` and in some place `tvec(:,3)==i` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a way to do it myself:

```
 %J is the indexes of the first unique days ( eg. if there is multiple
    %data from january 1., the first time stamp from january 1. will be
    %the time samp for our output)
    [~,J,K] = unique(tvec(:,2:3),'rows');
    %preallocate
    tvec_ab = zeros(length(J),6);
    data_ab = zeros(length(J),4);   
    tvec_ab = tvec(J,:);
    %sum all data from the same days together column wise.
    for i = 1:4
        data_ab(:,i) = accumarray(K,data(:,i));
    end
    %set output
    data_a = data_ab;
    tvec_a = tvec_ab;
```

Thanks for your responses though

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized version (not fully tested)

```
[x y] = meshgrid(1:12,1:31);
XY=[x(:) Y(:)];
[I,loc]=ismember(XY,tvec(:,2:3),'rows');
tvec_ab(I)=tvec(loc(loc>0),:);
acm = accumarray(tvec(:,2:3),data);
data_ab(I) = acm(sub2ind(size(acm),tvec(:,2),tvec(:,3)));
```